# Editing a Wordpress Site Locally?

Tags: sql, wordpress, local

Okay, so I'm helping a friend out with his site (that he designed in wordpress). I don't like the idea of working solely on a live site, so I copied it down to my local server on my mac. Here's the issues I'm having in terms of editing it.

1. Editing via SQL (SequelPro), throws the site back to nothing, even if I make a VERY slight change in the html that one would see on the Wordpress end.
2. Even if I try to go to the local site admin, it leads to the live. Any ideas on this? localsite/wp-admin ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. What do you mean, "throws back to nothing"? You'll need to provide a bit more detail on what HTML you're adding, and where you're adding it.
2. When you move a Wordpress site to another domain/location whether they be local or otherwise, you need to do a find replace on the MySQL exported file to replace livesite.com with localsite.dev, otherwise Wordpress will keep linking to the livesite.com.

Comment: I would edit it via SQL locally, and it would automatically delete the content on the local site.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the wp-config.php file to override the site url settings that are in the database.

```
define( HOME_URL, 'http://localhost' );
define( WP_SITEURL, 'http://localhost' );  //This is where WordPress is installed.
```

This will allow you to access the site locally.

Comment: you can also change this from the dashborad or directly in the database if needed.

Comment: Yes but this method does not change the database it only overrides the option.  Mostly helpful if you can't access the dashboard.